# What would be best algorithm for encrypting small user info token in url query params

Tags: encryption, query-string

I have two applications.

Application 1 has user info stored in its database. It will generate a small token that consists of user info.

Application 1 will send generated token to Application 2 in a GET request with token in query params.

Example:

```
http://www.app2.com?token=<token_generated_by_app1>
```

Application 2 will use the token and consider that the user in the token logged in for the application 2 session.

Now to ensure the security of the token, it needs to be encrypted.

**What would be a good encryption algorithm for this use case?**

**Update:**

After some searching, I found JWT has a variant call JWE which includes encryption.

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7516

Comment: Who are you trying to protect the token from? If it is anybody on the Internet then enable TLS/https. If you want to protect it from the administrators or network operators of the companies that operate application 1 and 2, then you probably can't. It might depend on why the token must be shared in the first place.

Comment: You get it wrong. Token encryption is not for securing it in the internet layer. It is to ensure no one else can generate a valid token.

Comment: What info does the token contains, exactly?

Comment: Then you need a JWS which you might combine with JWE. I guess you're re-implementing OAuth 2.0.

Comment: @Alejandro token will contain user information. Application 2 will authenticate a user with a valid token.

Comment: @ArtjomB. Ya, I am thinking to go with RS256 with 2048 bit keys. We just need user info to signed with an algorithm that provides Integrity, Authenticity, Non-repudiation & Confidentiality.

Comment: @Ibrahim What information? How does the receiving program uses it to authenticate the user?